# Java Scanner and Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: java, file-io, for-loop, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I'm having some trouble figuring out why this isn't working. Any ideas?

```
      try {
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/baseball_in.txt"));
           String[][] myStringArray = new String [40][40];
           for (int i=0; scanner.hasNext(); i++) {
               for(int x=0; x<7; x++){
                   myStringArray[i][x] = scanner.next();
               }
           }
           System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myStringArray));
           scanner.close();
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          }
         }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what the problem is. "This isn't working" doesn't provide much for people to help you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Also why don't you use FileInputStream with BufferedReader if you want to add it to an Array or a set line by line (I presume)?

Comment: I am really trying to get it down to as few lines as possible, and Scanner seemed like the best choice, the error I get is      "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
 at examq1.Short2.main(Short2.java:15)"                               I'm not really sure what this means

Comment: @user1750156 It looks like you are trying to fetch element through `scanner` even if there is nothing left to fetch. Moreover `for (int i=0; scanner.hasNext(); i++)` look kind of weird. Better use `while`. If you can explain what you are trying to achieve then it will be easy for us to provide better help.

Comment: If find multi-arrays a pain to work with.  Since it doesn't look like performance isn't mission critical, you can try using lists inside of lists, List< List<String> >, Should be easier to work with and debug.  If you know a bit of math, you can also make a multi-array out of single array.

Comment: I know this just me being OC, but please please put scanner.close() in a finally {} block. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You only check if there's a next element in `scanner` every 7th time you call `scanner.next()`. So it's probable that `scanner` has no next elements to get when you call `scanner.next()` 7 times in a row.

Do:

```
try {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/baseball_in.txt"));
       String[][] myStringArray = new String [40][40];
       for (int i=0; scanner.hasNext(); i++) {
           for(int x=0; x<7 && scanner.hasNext(); x++){
               myStringArray[i][x] = scanner.next();
           }
       }
       System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myStringArray));
       scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
```

Comment: Even better would be to use a `while(scanner.hasNext())` loop as already mentioned by @Smit. That's the way you work with Enumerations or scanners. Then, of course, you'd need a variable i which indicates the row in your array where you want to add the String.